# PHP Mod_Rewrite css/images dont load

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, include

i got some problems with the mod_rewrite.

I want to redirect all requests to one page (app.php). It works fine:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond $1!^(app\.php|assets|editor|css|js|scripts|images|img|media|xml|user_guide|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Okay so when i want to bind an css file, for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../app/templates/style.css">
```

The chrome browser "firebug" shows me

```
style.css  /app/templates GET 200 OK
```

But the css isnt include.
I google for hours and didnt find anything. Even on stackoverflow i try'd some solutions.
Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is coming due to your use of relative URLs for css/js/images.

You have 2 options to fix it:

1. Just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
2. You can try adding this in your page's header:

**UPDATE:**

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond $1 !^(app\.php|assets|editor|css|js|scripts|templates|images|img|media|xml|user_guide|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
  RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|jpe?g|gif|png|tiff)$
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ app.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hey. I try the absolute path "http://localhost/app/templates/style.css" but it still not works. Chrome still says "200 GET OK"

I cant try your second solution because there is nothing coming after the ":"

Comment: If you enter this css link in browser do you see your css code?

Comment: Nope i dont see it. But it is there on this location.

Comment: If you don't see anything then of course browser will also not see it.

Comment: If you comment out your existing rule does it help?

Comment: Well it works then if i use the style.css wich is in the same directory as the app.php. If i want to place the css file in another directory it wont work.